# Sentence correction and Recommendation needed

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Can I write " the juxtaposition of the two contrasting dispostions , is merely  two sides of the same coin." ? Is the sentence gramatically correct?  Also, does it succesfully convey the notion that benefit of mixing cultures both can be viewed from two different angles producing contransting opinions. Both merits and reasons to carp about, depending which angle you chose to see it from.

Comment: You can't say *is merely two*. You could say *is merely the conjunction of two*. But whether you use *is* or *are* it needs to match the singularity or plurality of both the first part of the sentence and the second part of the sentence. Perhaps *is like having two sides*.

Answer (score -1):

If you omit the comma (and correct the misspelling of 'dispositions') your sentence is grammatical.There is something not quite right about it, however, perhaps because the thought behind it has been compressed too tightly. You might try to use a different metaphor than two sides of a coin; it is a bit too vivid. The one thing that no-one can do is to juxtapose (that is put next to each other) the two sides of the same coin.